# Procedure -'executed as'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I create the following proc

```
ALTER PROCEDURE secret 
WITH EXECUTE AS ... 
AS
begin
end
```

i want to find out (by query) which user account the Database Engine uses to validate permissions on this object?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_name();
```

More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188014.aspx

Comment: No.I try it.its give me dbo. i need the user name that gave his permission to execuete this sp

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is that it may not be available if you weren't specifically capturing that information. And you'd capture that information with a DDL trigger typically. If this is something that you think you're going to be interested in going forward, set this up now so you can answer this question for next time.

Another option that you have (assuming that the information hasn't rolled off) is to look in the default trace. According to [this article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/the-default-trace-in-sql-server---the-power-of-performance-and-security-auditing/), one of the things it captures is "Audit Schema Object GDR events" where "GDR" is "grant/deny/revoke". In other words, exactly what you're looking for. If it happened a while ago, though, you're going to be out of luck.

However, you can check in the sys.database_permissions system view. Do something like:

```
select user_name(grantor_principal_name)
from sys.database_permissions
where major_id = object_id('yourProcedure')
and grantee_principal_id = user_id('yourUser')
```

Most of the time, however, this is going to return 'dbo' which is entirely accurate if it was run by, for instance, someone on your DBA team. Which is super likely.

Comment: the query and the trace do not return the expected answer. the query returns empty and the trace does not provide any GDR info.

Comment: Well then,  the information isn't available. Like i said in the first paragraph, you have t to be set up to capture that information if it's important to you. Write that ddl trigger now so you'll have it in place for next time.

Comment: Also curious why the downvote... I can't change reality.